# selnium chromedriver.exe executable needs to be in PATH [dup]

Tags: selenium

## selenium not work, and tried many things

i know this has been ask allllllllot, but i dont know what's going on my computer

```
    1. added enviorment path
    2. basically put chromedriver.exe every location in my file
    3. correct version (chromedriver and chrome)
    4. added executable_path
    5. i can opne chromedriver.exe in cmd
```

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe')`

all above is not work, i just wanna use selenium,any good idea? except reload system? (win10)

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZq4W.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the image picture , your chromedriver is clearly in the wrong path. Go to your command prompt , and run 
chromedriver.exe

See if you are not able to execute it , it means that the path is incorrect.

**Remedy**

1) you need to make sure you have install Chrome.
2) Get the latest chrome driver [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
3) Set path in your environment 
[image: environment]

4) In your script , this alone should work

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: 1. done 
2. yes
3. did set
= = Nothing changed. why chromedriver is in wrong path ??